# Is there MIPI host support now for intel realsense cameras? How do I connect it?

Tags: realsense

I am trying to avoid using a USB connection with the host SoC and trying to connect a D4 vision processor board to a host SoC(Pi CM4) using MIPI. This is done because the IO board only has usb 2 controllers.
Has the firmware update 5.15.1.0 added software support for the same? How do I connect MIPI on the D4 vision processor board? I have not been able to find any D4 board with a MIPI out but the datasheet does indicate this is possible. Are there specific boards with this capability?